# Adding header to RecyclerView Paging 3 according to a condition from API response

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3

I have implemented Pager 3 for my RecyclerView. Now I have to add a header to my recycler view if the API response has a flag set.

What I am doing now is when i get the response, I set this flag to a static variable then in the ViewModel check for this variable before adding header like this:

```
//PagingDataSource
override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, UIModel> {
        val position = params.key ?: STARTING_PAGE_INDEX
        val response = getUseCase(
            orgId = orgId,
            isPhysical = null,
            limit = params.loadSize,
            page = position
        )
    // SETTING FLAG HERE
    AppVariable.SessionData.myFlag = response.data.flag ?:false
    return LoadResult.Page(
                        data = response.data.data,
                        prevKey = if (position == STARTING_PAGE_INDEX) null else position - 1,
                        nextKey = if (data.isEmpty()) null else position + 1
                    )
}
```

In viewModel i am checking like this:

```
 fun fetchData(): Flow<PagingData<UIModel>> {
     val flow = Pager(
            ...
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                PagingDataSource(
                    ...
                )
            }
        ).flow
            .map { pagingData ->
                //ISSUE HERE
                if (AppVariables.SessionData.myFlag) { 
                        return@map pagingData.insertHeaderItem(
                            TerminalSeparatorType.SOURCE_COMPLETE,
                            UIModel.ActivateCardHeader
                        )
                    }
                pagingData
                }
             return flow
     }
```

Now the issue is that the if condition is getting invoked before I get the response from the server, and after I get the response from the server this if condition is not getting invoked(I know this because I tried setting debug points and it's not hitting after the API response.) If call recyclerViewAdapter.refresh() my header becomes visible.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 possible ways to this solution

1. Create a function and call it after getting the response
   from the API inside the `onResponse` method.
2. or Try using a callback for the response like

**Using Callback**

```
interface MyCallback {
        fun onResponse(flag: Boolean)
    }
```

and inside your own response after getting the result call the `onResponse` method using the instance `MyCallback` instance and modify the recycler view inside the overridden `onResponse` method according to `flag` parameter.

> To learn about interfaces, check out [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/interfaces.html#properties-in-interfaces)

Answer (score 0):

The `AppVariables.SessionData.myFlag` type must be a flow or state flow then you can use map and flattenConcact operator to achive this functionallity. your code must be like this:

```
    fun fetchData(): Flow<PagingData<UIModel>> {
        return AppVariables.SessionData.myFlag.map { myFlag ->
            Pager(
                ...
            pagingSourceFactory = {
                PagingDataSource(
                    ...
                )
            }).flow.map { pagingData ->
                if (myFlag) {
                    pagingData.insertHeaderItem(
                    TerminalSeparatorType.SOURCE_COMPLETE,
                    UIModel.ActivateCardHeader
                    )
                }
                pagingData
            }
        }.flattenConcat()
    }
```

with map operator in every change in flag new instance of pager will be returned.
`flattenConcat` operator for convert `Flow<Flow<Any>>` to `Flow<Any>`